# How to rotate an entire healpix map in healpy?

Tags: python, astronomy, healpy

I have a healpy map with about 2.5 million elements. I would like to rotate the map by about 45 degrees clockwise. I cannot find a healpy function to do this in a straightforward manner. I suppose I could convert all pixels to theta/phi and then rotate, but each pixel has a corresponding intensity value that needs to remain intact during the rotation.

Is there a more straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: Hi Jake, welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for us to best help you, please provide an example of what output you're currently getting as well as what output you expect to get, embedded in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `rotate_map_alms`:

https://healpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/healpy.rotator.Rotator.rotate_map_alms.html

but first you need to create a `healpy.Rotator` https://healpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/healpy.rotator.Rotator.html#healpy.rotator.Rotator and pass the 45 deg angle in radians through the `rot` argument.